# Using Prepare select statements in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having the below code where I am querying the MySQL database. I need to replace my select query to prepare statement

```
  public static void ValidateName(List<Employees> EmpList, string Grp)
    {
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string selectQuery;

        for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
        {
           selectQuery = "Select EmpName from Employee where group = @Grp  AND @Name in (FirstName, LastName);";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grp", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Grp;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmpList[i].Name;
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                if (lineList.Count <=0)
                {
                   WriteValidationFailure(EmpList[i], "Name doesnot exists in the DB");
                }
                conn.Close();
        }       
      }
    }
```

This code works perfectly. But for improvement I need to use  the prepare statements instead of the query I  am using. Because I am having similar kinds of various validation in my code, I am not sure how to reuse the parameters effectively.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the SqlCommand.Prepare method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Since you are targeting MySQL: [MySqlCommand.Prepare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Prepare.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You are very close.  Just call `cmd.Prepare()`, keep references to the parameters, and reuse the command:

```
public static void ValidateName(List<Employees> EmpList, string Grp)
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    string selectQuery;
    selectQuery = "Select EmpName from Employee where group = @Grp  AND @Name in (FirstName, LastName);";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
        {           
            var prmGrp = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grp", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            var prmName = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Prepare();
            for (int i = 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
            {
                prmGrp.Value = Grp;
                prmName.Value = EmpList[i].Name;

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lineList.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    if (lineList.Count <=0)
                    {
                        WriteValidationFailure(EmpList[i], "Name doesnot exists in the DB");
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        conn.Close();
    }           
}
```